# Javascript console log in UIWebView in Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview, console.log

Is there any way to print logs that is created by "console.log" in web page in UIWebView or WKWebView in swift (like Chrome F12.)

Have a nice days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic implementation for the `UIWebView`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the web view.
        let webView = UIWebView()
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com.py")!))
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let js = "console.log = function() {window.location = 'logger://webview?' + JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}"
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: js)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.url?.scheme == "logger" {
            guard let data = request.url?.query?.removingPercentEncoding?.data(using: .utf8) else { return true }
            guard let obj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else { return true }
            guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: obj, options: .prettyPrinted) else { return true }
            guard let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) else { return true }
            print(json)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
console.log(4, 3.53, 'Hello', {d: {f: 4}}, function() {}, undefined, null, true)
```

Prints the following in Xcode log:

```
[
  4,
  3.5299999999999998,
  "Hello",
  {
    "d" : {
      "f" : 4
    }
  },
  null,
  null,
  null,
  true
]
```

**Caveats**

- This only prints logs executed after the page has loaded.
- Since we're using JSON.stringify, we can't print the following types: `function`, `undefined`
- Since we're using JSON.stringify, `true` and `false` are
  printed as `1` and `0`, respectively